# PHP / LDAP on inexpensive hosting plan

Tags: php, ldap, web-hosting, shared-hosting

For my login system, I would like to check a username and password against a remote LDAP server using PHP.

Can anyone tell me if just checking a user against LDAP will work on an inexpensive hosting plan from a company such as GoDaddy, 1&1, or Dreamhost?

Ex:

```
$objConn = ldap_connect($strDomain);
```

I don't want to run an LDAP server, just simply use the LDAP functions of PHP to verify an account.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to email their respective support departments and ask this exact question; I'm sure they'll be able to help you. Everyone's setup is likely to be different, so this is probably the best approach. As long as the support is compiled-in and you've got network connectivity to your LDAP host (which you should probably access over SSL/TLS, if possible), you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a 10+ yr Dreamhost client and had this same question.  The response from DH Support team was less than helpful, but I found this nugget:

> The cURL library ('libcurl') ... currently supports the http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file, and ***ldap*** protocols.

Source: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216688028-cURL-overview

Also, very helpful cURL debugging info at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Haven't gotten the authentication worked out just yet, but I'm getting closer with this.